# How to create folder and upload files using the OCS owncloud API

Tags: node.js, api, owncloud, ocs

I am developing an app that use an owncloud OCS API.

I used the [Owncloud REST API](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/developer_manual/core/ocs-share-api.html) for manage users and now I want to manage the files of each user. I am using nodejs. Is an API for manage files like manage users one?

What I found was the API URL for shared files:

```
owncloud/ocs/v1.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/shares
```

This returns only the shared files. I want one for the all the files

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CURL command we use:

- `curl -X MKCOL <folder_URL>` for create a folder
- `curl -X PUT <folder_URL>/<file_name> --data-binary @<file_location_in_pc>` for upload a file.

This is an example of the code:

```
/**
   * Upload a file to an user folder
   * @param userId
   * @param fileName
   * @param fileLocation
   * @param callback
   */
  function fnUploadDocument(userId, fileName, fileLocation, callback) {
    var json = {
      done: false
    }
    var command = 'curl -X PUT "'
    command += srv.ownclouddirUtil.getUrlUser()
    command += srv.h3apifolder + userId + '/'
    command += fileName + '"'
    command += ' --data-binary @"' + fileLocation + '"'
    console.log('Command--: ', command)
    srv.fileSystemService.runScript(command, function (stdout, error, stderr) {
      if (error === null) {
        json.done = true
        callback(json)
      } else {
        json.error = error
        json.stderr = stderr
        callback(json)
      }
    })
  }
```